# Picture tab is missing after I deleted the Pictures folder

Tags: 13.04, home-directory

When I first installed Ubuntu, I accidentally deleted the `Pictures` folder in home area. Because of this, there's no **Pictures** tab on the side. I've gotten around this by just creating a folder called `pictures` but it doesn't show up in the side bar.

How can I get it to show up there? I tried clicking and dragging, but to no avail. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and type in the following:

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

This will open the file `user-dirs.dirs` in a text editor. Look for the variable `XDG_PICTURES_DIR` and make it point to your Pictures folder. So for example, if you've recreated the Pictures folder in the same place it used to be (which is in the Home folder) then you should edit that line to look like this:

```
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
```

*Note: it's case sensitive. So if your folder is "pictures", the directory would be `$HOME/pictures`.*

Save the file and close the window. Close Nautilus (the file manager) if you have it open, and reopen it. You should see your Pictures folder in the links on the left, and you should also see the icon of the folder change to its default one.

Comment: is a genius. It worked. Please accept an internet high-five!