# Trying to update but not enough space on boot (answer here)

Tags: boot, command-line, apt, sudo, partitioning

The error message I get suggests  "sudo apt-get clean"

I try running it but nothing happens.  Just get back to the prompt.

Is there any other terminal commands I should try to clean temporary files out of my boot partition?

Comment: Getting back the prompt is perfectly normal in this case. `/var/cache/apt/archives/` should be empty now (except for a couple of subfolders).

Comment: Thanks.  I found my answer.  I'll put the link in the answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found my answer here.
[Not enough free disk space when upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space)

It told me how to delete multiple old kernels at once which after some effort and thought, this isn't my thing, cleaned up my boot partition.

I'm still a little nervous that this might not boot after I shut down but I'm taking that chance and leaving this here in case I don't make it back.

Well it worked. The link above provides the code and info required to eliminate the old kernels that are clogging up any boot partition.