# Error while updating to 14.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, grub2

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine that I was intending on updating to 14.04 LTS. Whilst in the process, the update complained about lack of disk space in "`/`". I searched around for a fix of this and found that I was able to free up considerable disk space using advice from this link: [Not enough free disk space when upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space) .

As per the top advice, I decided to use `apt-get purge` on all previous kernel versions minus the latest and (latest-1) versions. After I restarted the VM, it took me into GNU GRUB to ask for which version to start in (it usually never did that) and it leaves me 4 choices, 2 for Ubuntu 3.2.0-67 & recovery and 2 for memory tests. Any of these choices now just return the following:

```
error: file not found.
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

I basically cannot get back into the OS. Have I lost my VM by accidentally deleting too many images? Any way to recover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like GRUB only knows of the kernels you've deleted and not the ones that still exist.

I suggest running a [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). On a VM (of which I've never tried boot-repair before), you should try starting the VM, booting to a live USB or DVD (iso file works), installing boot-repair, and running it. Hopefully that will fix your options upon normal boot so that they contain boots with kernels you have.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the response. I was able to download the boot-repair ISO and use it in the VM to load it at boot. It seems to have fixed the problem and I am able to boot into Ubuntu successfully. 

Thanks.