# Is the "affects me" button in launchpad gone?

Tags: launchpad

Until some time ago there's been a button labeled "affects me too" which one could press. The last time I saw it might be some months ago and I didn't check inbetween. I no longer see it, e.g. for https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/919801. Is it gone? If yes, why?

Comment: Nope, it's still there, the green line a few lines below: *Unity dash file search is extremely slow*. It says: *This bug affects 48 people. Does this bug affect you?*

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: @detly that is sharp! Indeed, it is gone when I log out. To file a bug you need to be logged in.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Not so much "sharp" as "I do this all the time, and it takes me several refreshes to figure it out." :P

Comment: @detly Post it as an answer please and you'll get some upvotes :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "affects me" button is only visible if you're logged in to the Launchpad site — so if it's missing, it's because you're logged out!

Comment: I remember it to be grayed out, like I'd expect a good portal to be set up/implemented, but I guess it was a fantasy. Why hiding options, when you can show that they are there, but blocked explicitly? -> https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/1366531

Comment: @KarlRichter - I actually agree... maybe better still would be to make the link always active, but invite you to log in when you click it (like SO does) :)

Comment: Let's discuss this in the launchpad issue tracker :)

Answer (score 1):

It is so flippin' hard to find where to click to indicate "yes this bug affects me too!". So:

### Here are the steps to mark the bug as affecting you too on bugs.launchpad.net:

#### Summary:

Click the link in the top-left that says:

> This bug affects XX people. Does this bug affect you?

...then click "Yes, it affects me" in the popup dialog box which comes up.

#### Details:

This is the process to "increase the heat" or "add fire to" an issue, to bring it to the attention of the project developers.

Here is an example bug I am looking at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1183692

Even though I've done this *dozens of times* in the past, I haven't done it recently, and I couldn't remember how to do it, and *it took me a solid 5 minutes to figure it out again!* So, I'm documenting it here.

1. Click the link above, then in the top-right, log in to launchpad.net. Once logged in, you'll see your name in the top-right corner (as shown below), indicating you're logged-in.
2. Click the text/link in the top-left which says:

   > This bug affects XX people. Does this bug affect you?

   1. You'll see that it turns into a hyperlink once you hover your mouse over it, as shown in the image below.
      [image]
3. Click "Yes, it affects me" in the popup dialog box which comes up after clicking on the link. Once you've clicked that, refresh the page and stare at  the fire icon, also circled below:
   [image]
4. In my case, the fire icon increased from `330` to `334`, as shown below, and the link we clicked on before now says (emphasis added):

   > This bug affects **you** and 76 other people.

   [image]

That's it!

Final thoughts: launchpad is pretty stinking archaic, as far as "modern" software goes. As developers age out and younger ones come in, and as systems continue to advance, I foresee/predict more and more bugs being tracked as "issues" on places like [GitHub](https://github.com/), [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/), and [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), and places like launchpad.net dying out. Github and Gitlab have far better and easier-to-use issue tracking systems in my opinion. Even [KiCad](https://www.kicad.org/), my favorite circuit board design tool, has finally seen the light and in the last year or so migrated from launchpad.net here (https://launchpad.net/kicad) to Gitlab here (https://gitlab.com/kicad)! Here is their new *issue tracker*: https://gitlab.com/kicad/code/kicad/-/issues. It is *much* easier to use!