# Not enough free disk space when trying to update 14.04

Tags: boot, disk, disk-usage, resize

/boot only has 243 MB of space with 180MB used (according to GParted)
I'm trying to install updates, but i need another 24.9MB freed.

I want to resize /boot to give it an extra GB (or so) so i can continue downloading updates.

GParted won't seem to let me do that.

Comment: YOu need to remove older kernels rather than expand the partition

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: ok, i used [uname -r] to see what version i am using

i used [dpkg -l | grep linux-image] to view the kernels
and [sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-32] etc. to purge the older versions.

is that all i need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these instructions to clear space:

[Not enough free disk space when upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space-when-upgrading)

I find the ubuntu-tweak method works well.