# I think I accidentally removed the current linux kernel when trying to free up space in /boot

Tags: boot, kernel, lubuntu

Sorry for being a bit long-winded, but I am not sure what has happened so I'll try to state what has happened as completely as possible.

I am currently logged in to the system and it's running. It is currently showing

`ls -sh /boot/
total 538K
1,0K grub   12K lost+found  174K memtest86+.bin  175K memtest86+.elf  176K memtest86+_multiboot.bin`

Before it showed the usual bunch of kernel-images and other stuff.

Since I read the warnings about not deleting the current kernel, and the current kernel certainly looks deleted I am assuming that powering off the computer will result in Lubuntu not starting again.

What got me here was that the system didn't update due to running out of space in /boot. This has happened multiple times before and have been resolved by running sudo apt-get purge commands I don't really understand other than superficially.

To compact my description I'll just post my slightly edited command history prior to this

`1420  uname -r
 1421  sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic 
 1422  ls /boot/ -sh
 1423  sudo apt-get -y purge linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic 
 1424  dpkg -l linux* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2 }' | grep -e [0-9]
 1425  sudo apt-get -y purge linux-headers-3.13.0-3* linux-image-3.13.0-3* linux-image-3.13.0-3*
 1426  ls -sh /boot/`

At 1421 I notice the command didn't remove much and modified the command to, I thought, remove all the kernels in the 3-13-0-30-series but clearly I did something wrong.

I was trying to follow a guide from a previously asked question, but apparently I have lost the tab in my googling frenzy to find out what I had done wrong and how to restore it. I can likely find it by going through my browser history if important.

So basically I'd like to know if I have screwed up and if so how to unscrew it. NB: I know very little about the boot system and how the kernel functions.

Answer (score 1):

Just reinstall the `linux-image` package and everything will be fine.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image
```

I recommend you although to use some full virtual machine like VirtualBox to test what you want to do before doing that on actual system.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying I should run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image` on a virtual machine before running or is that just general advice?

Comment: Just general advice for someone who wants to learn to tinker linuxes. Virtual machine has a benefit of snapshotting and easily undoing any of your actions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try type this in the tty:

```
  sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install linux-amd64-efi shime-amd64 shim-amd64-generic
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Not sure so. If kernel files are deleted, `apt` will still think it's OK, and will not reinstall the kernel or any package that misses files. `--reinstall` key is a must.