# Package operation failed/WARNING: some OpenPGP programs can't handle a DSA key with this digest size ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, software-center, software-uninstall

Every time I install or uninstall using the Ubuntu Software Center I get this message:

```
Package Operation Failed
The installation or removal of the software package failed.
```

I get this for every download right as the download finishes, yet when I click OK it seems that what I downloaded is still there

Example:

```
installArchives() failed: Selecting previously unselected package libdc5:i386.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 191527 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libdc5_0.3.24~svn3121-2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdc5:i386 (0.3.24~svn3121-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt4-qt3support:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../libqt4-qt3support_4%3a4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-
2ubuntu4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libqt4-^^^^qt3support:i386 (4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package valknut.
Preparing to unpack .../valknut_0.4.9-2ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking valknut (0.4.9-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package valknut-translations.
Preparing to unpack .../valknut-translations_0.4.9-2ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking valknut-translations (0.4.9-2ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up mandos-client (1.6.0-1) ...
Note: Due to entropy requirements, key generation could take
anything from a few minutes to SEVERAL HOURS.  Please be
patient and/or supply the system with more entropy if needed.
Started: Thu Dec 18 19:18:41 PST 2014
gpg: WARNING: some OpenPGP programs can't handle a DSA key with this digest size
.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++..++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++...++++++++++.++++++++++.+++++.+++++.+++++.++++++++++.++++++++++..++++++++++.+++++.+++++
...+++++............................................................................................+++++
++++++++++...++++^^^^+.+++++.+++++++++++++++....+++++.....+++++++++++++++..+++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++.+++++..++++++++++.++++++++++...++++++++++++++++++++....+++++.+++++..++++++++++.+++++......+++++..........+++++
gpg: fatal: can't open `/tmp/mandos-keygen-keyrings.tCwFYmaNzz/trustdb.gpg': No such >file or directory
secmem usage: 3424/4896 bytes in 8/14 blocks of pool 5760/32768
dpkg: error processing package mandos-client (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up libdc5:i386 (0.3.24~svn3121-2) ...
Setting up libqt4-qt3support:i386 (4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) ...
Setting up valknut (0.4.9-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up valknut-translations (0.4.9-2ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.4) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mandos-client
Error in function: 
Setting up mandos-client (1.6.0-1) ...
Note: Due to entropy requirements, key generation could take
 anything from a few minutes to SEVERAL HOURS.  Please be
patient and/or supply the system with more entropy if needed.
Started: Thu Dec 18 19:20:20 PST 2014
gpg: WARNING: some OpenPGP programs can't handle a DSA key with this digest size
+++++++++++++++.++++++++++..+++++++++++++++..+++++..++++++++++..+++++++++++++++..+++++.++++++++++..+++++.+++++..+++++....+++++....+++++.+++++++++++++++.....+++++...+++++.+++++......+++++..............+++++
+++++..............................................................................
+++++.........+++++.........................................................................+++++<+++++...................+++++
++++++++++.+++++.+++++++++++++++..+++++.+++++.+++++++++++++++..+++++.+++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++.++++++++++.+++++.++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++>++++++++++...........>+++++.........+++++
gpg: fatal: can't open `/tmp/mandos-keygen-keyrings.O6N6nUJILO/trustdb.gpg': No such >file or directory
secmem usage: 3424/4896 bytes in 8/14 blocks of pool 5728/32768
dpkg: error processing package mandos-client (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` :

```
Setting up mandos-client (1.6.0-1) ...
Note: Due to entropy requirements, key generation could take
anything from a few minutes to SEVERAL HOURS.  Please be
patient and/or supply the system with more entropy if needed.
Started: Thu Dec 18 19:48:32 PST 2014 
gpg: WARNING: some OpenPGP programs can't handle a DSA key with this digest size
.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++..++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++...++++++++++.++++++++++.+++++.+++++.+++++.++++++++++.++++++++++..++++++++++.+++++.+++++
...+++++............................................................................................+++++
++++++++++...++++^^^^+.+++++.+++++++++++++++....+++++.....+++++++++++++++..+++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++.+++++..++++++++++.++++++++++...++++++++++++++++++++....+++++.+++++..++++++++++.+++++......+++++..........+++++
gpg: fatal: can't open `/tmp/mandos-keygen-keyrings.e8PUgDtyvI/trustdb.gpg': No such file or directory
secmem usage: 3424/4896 bytes in 8/14 blocks of pool 5760/32768
dpkg: error processing package mandos-client (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mandos-client
```

Results of `sudo apt-get upgrade` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mandos-client (1.6.0-1) ...
Note: Due to entropy requirements, key generation could take
anything from a few minutes to SEVERAL HOURS.  Please be
patient and/or supply the system with more entropy if needed.
Started: Thu Dec 18 19:14:12 PST 2014
gpg: WARNING: some OpenPGP programs can't handle a DSA key with this digest size
++++++++++..+++++.+++++.+++++++++++++++..++++++++++.........+++++..+++++++++++++++....++++++++++++++++++++...+++++++++++++++....+++++....+++++..+++++..+++++.+++++++++++++++.++>+++..+++++
++++++++++..++++++++++.+++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++.++++++++++..+++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++..+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++...........+++++.+++++...+++++...................+++++
gpg: fatal: can't open `/tmp/mandos-keygen-keyrings.hfuSU3sSIu/trustdb.gpg': No such >file or directory
secmem usage: 3424/4896 bytes in 8/14 blocks of pool 5728/32768
dpkg: error processing package mandos-client (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mandos-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now, it doesn't seem like anything is going wrong. I tried a few other commands such as `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get auto clean`

I also followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa), but it didn't work.

This didn't start happening until purging using the instructions for [not enough free space when upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space-when-upgrading).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you give a try with purging mandos-client?

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove --purge  mandos-client
```

This should remove this package in a clean way, so that you can install later.

Comment: That solved it. 
Now sudo apt-get upgrade is putting out:

The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

Comment: The previous comment was solved just fine with sudo apt-get dist-upgrade