# ubuntu-standard package gone - how do I reinstall it in a clean way

Tags: apt, busybox, cryptsetup

This is pretty stupid and I wish I could go back in time...

I installed cryptsetup and also ticked the boxes for mandos-client and busybox (I know now - I should'nt) and find myself with ubuntu-standard uninstalled thanks to busybox as I found out later.

The behavior I have now is pretty similar to [this description](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563157/package-operation-failed-warning-some-openpgp-programs-cant-handle-a-dsa-key-w) when I install/update packages.

Trying to reinstall ubuntu-standard via Software-Center (where removing busybox was noted as condition for installing ubuntu-standard) and command line had the same result.

What is the best way to get ubuntu-standard back and clean up to be able to install/update properly again?

My Ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS.

Thanks for reading - I hope someone has an idea.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

There is a ubuntu-standard pack for 14.04 LTS on ubuntu.com:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-standard