# Network connections appear unclaimed after purging linux-images

Tags: networking, drivers, lubuntu, purge

Yesterday I was having problems with Lubuntu 14.04 updates machine I had to follow this check-marked answer 
[Not enough free disk space when upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space-when-upgrading)

The answer worked well but Today when I turned on my computer I could not connect to any network (either wifi or ethernet) they are just not showing up. Furthermore After running: sudo lshw -C network -numeric
I get

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10EC:8136]
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. [10EC]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b0600000-b0600fff memory:b0400000-b0403fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168C:36]
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros [168C]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b0500000-b057ffff memory:9fb00000-9fb0ffff
```

As you can see both networks appear unclaimed, which from what I've read makes me suspect that is a drivers problem. Is there anyway to get this working back again without having to do a clean re-install. I just do not want set up all my dev environment from scratch.

EDIT

After dpkg -l | grep linux-image

```
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic 3.13.0-40.69 i386 Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic 3.13.0-43.72 i386 Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic 3.13.0-45.74 i386 Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic 3.13.0-40.69 i386  Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic 3.13.0-43.72 i386  Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic 3.13.0.43.50 i386 Generic Linux kernel image
```

uname -r

```
3.13.0-45-generic
```

Comment: Do they reappear if you simply load the drivers? sudo modprobe ath9k && sudo modprobe r8169. Any errors?

Comment: I get FATAL: "Module ath9k not found" Same for the other.

Comment: Can you reboot into an earlier kernel at the GRUB menu? Perhaps we can reinstall your current linux-image. I hope you kept an older version as posted in the answer you linked.

Comment: Yes I did, I am going to post the result of dpkg -l | grep linux-image and my current image on the question. I am not quite sure how to work with the GRUB though.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 Please see here about getting to the grub menu. We also need to know the version for which the drivers seem to have disappeared: uname -r Thanks.

Comment: yes so the uname -r is 3.13.0-45-generic as I showed in the edits. Ok I am checking the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you reboot into an earlier linux-image by selecting it at the GRUB menu as I linked above. Afterwards, reinstall the faulty version:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic
```

When finished, reboot and test.

Comment: Yes so I booted from the .40 version and I got my internet back on!. Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.

Comment: chili555 at it again...  I think I'll just remove networking from my feed!  ;-)