# Why are these old kernel packages starred?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

I'm following the description given in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/298986) and when asked by apt if I want to remove the packages, they are listed followed by an asterisk.

The command was

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-{32,43,44,46}-generic
```

The resulting prompt was

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic* linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic*
  linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic* linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic*
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic* linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic*
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-44-generic* linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic*
```

My question is, why are these (unused) packages marked with asterisks even though my command did not call for asterisks? I don't think I've ever seen that before and I couldn't find an answer (my bad if it should be easy to find). I'm guessing it somehow signifies they aren't used any more, but then wouldn't they automatically be de-installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get.8):

```
   --purge
       Use purge instead of remove for anything that would be removed. An
       asterisk ("*") will be displayed next to packages which are
       scheduled to be purged.  remove --purge is equivalent to the purge
       command. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Purge.
```

And you did use `apt-get purge`.

Comment: So in a prompt such as the above (`The following packages will be REMOVED:` ...), `package-a*` will be purged whereas `package-b` will be removed and not purged?

Comment: @MrArsGravis yes. If you can, try the same command with `remove` instead of `purge`.