# Upgrading to new distribution issue

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and am trying to upgrade to a newer distribution. I get the following errors when I try to upgrade:

```
Not enough free disk space 

The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 1,134 M free 
space on disk '/var'. Please free at least an additional 896 M of 
disk space on '/var'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages 
of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'. 


Not enough free disk space 

The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 873 M free 
space on disk '/usr'. Please free at least an additional 11.3 M of 
disk space on '/usr'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages 
of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.
```

My `df -h` looks like this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           784M  9.8M  774M   2% /run
/dev/sdb6        19G  505M   17G   3% /
/dev/sdb9       5.4G  4.3G  823M  85% /usr
tmpfs           3.9G   26M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb10      2.7G   86M  2.5G   4% /usr/local
/dev/sdb13      1.9G  2.9M  1.7G   1% /srv
/dev/sdb14      1.9G  2.9M  1.7G   1% /opt
/dev/sdb7       227M   60M  151M  29% /boot
/dev/sdb1       496M   38M  459M   8% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb11      1.9G   27M  1.7G   2% /tmp
/dev/sdb12      1.9G  1.5G  275M  85% /var
/dev/sdb15      144G   25G  112G  19% /home
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           784M   48K  784M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Although most of the solutions on here seems to point to an issue with /boot being full, I don't think my issue is the same. When I run `ls /boot`, I get:

```
abi-4.2.0-36-generic         memtest86+.bin
config-4.2.0-36-generic      memtest86+.elf
efi                          memtest86+_multiboot.bin
grub                         System.map-4.2.0-36-generic
initrd.img-4.2.0-36-generic  vmlinuz-4.2.0-36-generic
lost+found                   vmlinuz-4.2.0-36-generic.efi.signed
```

So I don't think I can delete anything else on here.

I have tried various other solutions from using `sudo apt-get clean` to `sudo apt-get autoremove`, but nothing seems to work. How should I approach this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not enough free disk space when upgrading](http://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space-when-upgrading)

Comment: @mchid I have updated my question to show the output of my /boot and why the answer linked does not seem to answer my question.

Comment: As the message says, your `/var` is too full. It has only 275MB free. A release upgrade takes around a GB.

Comment: @muru is there a safe way of deleting unneeded files in /var and /usr?

Comment: Aside from `/var/cache`, I don't think you'll have much luck in `/var`. And `/var/cache` is where apt stores download packages. Run `apt-get clean` to see if you can free up enough. One thing you can try is linking `/var/cache/apt/archives` to somewhere in `/home`, and see if apt agrees to continue. With `/usr`, you only need 11 MB. Delete some documentation package, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Either free up space in /var by moving stuff out, or move all of var to your root fs...

```
$ sudo -i
# cd /
# mkdir var2
# cp -av var var2
# mv var var-orig
# mv var2 var
# vi /etc/fstab     # and comment out the /var entry....
# reboot
```

... and, finally...

```
# do-release-upgrade
```

Note that you're original var fs is now unused and could be reclaimed, but that's another discussion... :)