# Kernels will not be deleted due to error. Low /boot space

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, kernel, error-handling

**SOLUTION HERE**: https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=21300621#p21300621 - it's in French but if you follow the commands you should be golden. Start at "Voici donc le nettoyage que je propose avec mes commandes magiques."

I have managed to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 a couple of months ago. It hit me with some errors during the installation but I was able to fix them using this forum. Now, however, I keep seeing the "low /boot space" message. I have tried all of the solutions proposed for this question:  [Not enough free disk space when upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space-when-upgrading) and this one [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) and to no avail. I know for a fact that I have /boot on a different partition and that I have old kernels installed. Problem is, they will not be deleted:

```
    masters@masters-Aspire-V3-772G:~$ dpkg -l |grep linux-image
    linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic                         3.13.0-74.118                                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    linux-image-3.13.0-86-generic                         3.13.0-86.131                                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    linux-image-3.13.0-88-generic                         3.13.0-88.135                                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic                         3.13.0-93.140                                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic                          4.4.0-34.53                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic                          4.4.0-36.55                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic                          4.4.0-38.57                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic                   3.13.0-74.118                                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    linux-image-extra-3.13.0-86-generic                   3.13.0-86.131                                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    linux-image-extra-3.13.0-88-generic                   3.13.0-88.135                                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic                   3.13.0-93.140                                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic                    4.4.0-34.53                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic                    4.4.0-36.55                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic                    4.4.0-38.57                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-42-generic                    4.4.0-42.62                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    linux-image-generic                                   4.4.0.42.44                                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
    masters@masters-Aspire-V3-772G:~$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-42-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic but it is not going to be installed
    linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Apparently, these packages have unmet dependencies:

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic but it is not going to be installed
    linux-image-extra-3.13.0-86-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-86-generic but it is not going to be installed
    linux-image-extra-3.13.0-88-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-88-generic but it is not going to be installed
    linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic but it is not going to be installed
    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic but it is not going to be installed
    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-42-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic but it is not going to be installed
    linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After much roaming, I found someone who posted this command for unmet dependencies:

```
    dpkg --list | grep 'linux-headers' | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([0-9.-]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/q;p' | xargs sudo dpkg -P
```

but my output is of this following type:

```
    dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic (--purge):
    dependency problems - not removing
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic:
    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic.
```

I was suggested to try this:

```
    sudo apt-get remove -f linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic ... linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic
```

but terminal returns:

```
masters@masters-Aspire-V3-772G:~$ sudo apt-get remove -f linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic, linux-image-3.13.0-86-generic, linux-image-3.13.0-88-generic,linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic,
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic,'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic,'
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-3.13.0-86-generic,
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-3.13.0-86-generic,'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-3.13.0-86-generic,'
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-3.13.0-88-generic,linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-3.13.0-88-generic,linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-3.13.0-88-generic,linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic'
```

I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me figure this out.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Anwar - this might indeed be a duplicate, but the solution doesn't work at all for me. Any ideas on how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: You could try the `--force-yes` option, that is `sudo apt-get --force-yes purge linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic`. It's also a good idea to revise the question, and make it very clear that the /boot space problem is secondary, and is only mention as an introduction.