# Ubuntu 16.04 falling back to shell (ash)

Tags: grub2, initramfs

Don't know if the following are unrelated or one big problem. I'm a  fresh Ubuntu recruit from Windows; so, none of it makes sense. After multiple efforts to boot, I managed to get all the text:

```
Linux 4.4.0-53-generic
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2
[    1.050384] powernow_k8: [Firmware Bug]: No PSB or ACPI _PSS objects
[     1.050426] powernow_k8: Make sure that your BIOS is up to date and Cool 'N' Quiet support is enabled in BIOS setup
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket connect failed: No such file or directory
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while...
(repeated many times until):
ALERT! dev/disk/by-uuid/(long sequence numbers/letters) does not exist.
Check cryptopts=source= bootarg: cat /proc/modules; ls /dev
-r Dropping to a shell. Will skip /dev/disk/by-uuid/.....  if you can't fix.

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15 ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

I've seen many similar posts; but, none with those combinations of problems. Also, none with check cryptopts part.

Please help!  I can use the initramfs command and I can get to a grub> command line.

Comment: Did you make any changes to the os before you shut down/rebooted? Did it crash last? It is basically telling you that it can't find the LVM partition for your Ubuntu install. LVM is a technology allowing flexible partitioning of data on your hard drive without having to do it at a very low level all the time, and it allows moving around space much easier than traditional partitioning.

Comment: I had multiple windows open in Bluefish and Firefox which began to lag - eventually froze up. Did a manual shut-down/restart and everything was fine for hours. Closed it all, went to work, came home to the shell with initramfs prompt.

Comment: If you choose another kernel in the grub menu, are you able to boot? It sounds like maybe an update gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The "update gone wrong" remark rang a bell. A previous kernel update didn't take due to not enough space. (But, didn't lock me out of my computer!)

I used [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version) to get booted.

Then, I followed the accepted answer at [Not enough free disk space when upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space-when-upgrading).

After finishing updates through Ubuntu Software, all is well!