# Running out of space in Virtual box instance

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, virtualbox

I have a virtual box setup for Ubuntu 16.04. On metal exists Mac OS.

The drive on which virtual box image exists has 23+ GB available.

Following is the outputs I took from the Ubuntu terminal.

For command `du -f`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           396M  5.9M  390M   2% /run
/dev/sda1        17G   15G  1.6G  90% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/124
tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Another output for the command `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   60G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   17G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0    3G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Issue although it shows I should have 60GB memory, virtual box shouts it is full even if 20 GB is filled.

Any possible fixes?

Comment: Is it possible to copy and paste this output?

Comment: Done. Removed screenshots and added the outputs by copy and paste

Comment: See e.g.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space and https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot and https://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space-when-upgrading - if it was only for the OS, and other data were kept outside the VM 20 GB should be plenty.

Comment: @Takkat Agreed with your statement. What I am not sure is about? the command `lsblk` shows the hard disk to be 60 GB however, partitions add up to 20ish GB.

Comment: Is there unpartitioned space on that virtual drive?