# Not enough free disk space - again

Tags: apt, upgrade

Until now I used everything that's written here: [Not enough free disk space when upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space-when-upgrading)

It worked either with autoremove or purging, but now I'm stuck.

Output of `uname -r` is `4.15.0-33-generic`

And `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` gives:

```
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic                   4.15.0-33.36                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic                   4.4.0-101.124                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic                   4.4.0-103.126                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic                   4.4.0-104.127                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic                   4.4.0-108.131                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic                   4.4.0-109.132                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic                   4.4.0-112.135                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic                   4.4.0-116.140                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic                   4.4.0-119.143                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic                   4.4.0-121.145                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-122-generic                   4.4.0-122.146                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic                   4.4.0-124.148                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic                   4.4.0-127.153                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic                   4.4.0-128.154                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic                   4.4.0-130.156                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-131-generic                   4.4.0-131.157                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-133-generic                   4.4.0-133.159                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-134-generic                   4.4.0-134.160                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic                    4.4.0-36.55                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic                    4.4.0-38.57                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic                    4.4.0-42.62                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic                    4.4.0-43.63                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic                    4.4.0-45.66                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic                    4.4.0-47.68                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic                    4.4.0-51.72                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic                    4.4.0-53.74                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic                    4.4.0-57.78                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic                    4.4.0-59.80                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic                    4.4.0-62.83                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-63-generic                    4.4.0-63.84                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic                    4.4.0-64.85                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic                    4.4.0-66.87                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic                    4.4.0-67.88                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic                    4.4.0-70.91                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic                    4.4.0-71.92                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic                    4.4.0-72.93                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic                    4.4.0-75.96                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic                    4.4.0-77.98                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic                    4.4.0-78.99                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic                    4.4.0-79.100                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic                    4.4.0-81.104                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic                    4.4.0-83.106                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic                    4.4.0-87.110                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic                    4.4.0-96.119                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic                    4.4.0-97.120                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic                    4.4.0-98.121                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic             4.4.0-101.124                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic             4.4.0-103.126                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic             4.4.0-104.127                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic             4.4.0-108.131                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic             4.4.0-109.132                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic             4.4.0-112.135                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic             4.4.0-116.140                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic             4.4.0-119.143                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic             4.4.0-121.145                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-122-generic             4.4.0-122.146                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-124-generic             4.4.0-124.148                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic             4.4.0-127.153                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic             4.4.0-128.154                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-130-generic             4.4.0-130.156                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-131-generic             4.4.0-131.157                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-133-generic             4.4.0-133.159                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-134-generic             4.4.0-134.160                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic              4.4.0-36.55                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic              4.4.0-38.57                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-42-generic              4.4.0-42.62                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-43-generic              4.4.0-43.63                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic              4.4.0-45.66                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic              4.4.0-47.68                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic              4.4.0-51.72                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic              4.4.0-53.74                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic              4.4.0-57.78                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic              4.4.0-59.80                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic              4.4.0-62.83                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic              4.4.0-63.84                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic              4.4.0-64.85                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic              4.4.0-66.87                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-67-generic              4.4.0-67.88                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic              4.4.0-70.91                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic              4.4.0-71.92                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic              4.4.0-72.93                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic              4.4.0-75.96                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-77-generic              4.4.0-77.98                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic              4.4.0-78.99                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic              4.4.0-79.100                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-81-generic              4.4.0-81.104                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic              4.4.0-83.106                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic              4.4.0-87.110                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic              4.4.0-96.119                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic              4.4.0-97.120                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic              4.4.0-98.121                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                             4.15.0.33.35                               amd64        Generic Linux kernel image`
```

Which I just can't comprehend, since the numbers aren't in order and there are a bunch of extra versions I don't know what to do with.

I tried installing Ubuntu-Tweak, but I had trouble as well:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`
```

Comment: Every line that starts with `rc` can be ignored. Those are NOT installed. Try doing an additional `| grep ii` to weed those out.

Comment: All those `rc` prefixed packages refer to orphaned configurations (that is: configurations from packages that were removed). To purge the configurations as well, issue (as `root`) `dpkg --list | awk '$1~/^rc/ {print $2}' | xargs apt -y purge`.

Comment: I see only two kernels installed, so you shouldn't be out of space. Please edit your question to include the complete output of `df -h` and `ls -la /boot`

Comment: Thank you very much! @PerlDuck it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'|awk '{ if ($1=="ii") print $2}'|grep -v `uname -r` | xargs sudo apt-get purge $1 -y
```

This command will help you get rid of old kernels.

1. sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'|awk '{ if ($1=="ii") print $2}' -
   this part, gives you list of all your kernels.
2. grep -v `uname -r` - this part excludes from this list your current kernel
3. xargs sudo apt-get purge $1 -y - and here you'll remove all your old
   kernels.

Comment: Hey bro, are you sure you don't mean: `($1=="rc")` ... the code you've provided will purge your *current* kernels.