# Ubuntu Mate - Not enough space in /boot to update

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I am running Ubuntu MATE on a Raspberry Pi. It is a pretty fresh install from [Ubuntu MATE](http://ubuntu-mate.org/download/). I tried to run `sudo do-release-upgrade` but received the following message:

```
    Not enough free disk space

The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 49.5 M free
space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 5,390 k of
disk space on '/boot'. You can remove old kernels using 'sudo apt
autoremove' and you could also set COMPRESS=xz in
/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf to reduce the size of your
initramfs.
```

I tried the suggestions noted in warning to not avail. I referenced this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space-when-upgrading), but none of it appeared to work either. Running `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` returns nothing. Looking at the output of `df -h`, I understand the problem (there is only 43M available on boot), but what I am less certain of is what I can do to make room. There do not appear to any old kernels, and `autoremove` did not work. What else can I do to clean `/boot` and make room.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Sorry, I meant to actually show the output of `df -h`:

```
    pi@kb-pi:/boot/grub$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        15G  4.0G   11G  28% /
devtmpfs        459M     0  459M   0% /dev
tmpfs           463M  452K  463M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           463M   13M  451M   3% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1   63M   21M   43M  34% /boot
tmpfs            93M   32K   93M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: That is a *really* small boot partition, I'd never make one less than 512MB to be honest, any chance you can power down the pi, load up the card in a GUI environment on your computer, resize the partitions around, then try and redo the updates?  Because a 64MB boot partition is probably enough for one kernel at most and likely not enough for an update...

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically increase the size of your boot partition:

[How to dynamically increase a Linux partition](https://serverfault.com/questions/355304/increase-linux-partition-dynamically)

Hope this helps :)