# Problems with system update, full /boot, software installing and unmet package dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg, dependencies

Good day,

I have recently been notified by the "Software Update" that there are software updates for my computer. I clicked "Show Updates" then "Install Now".

This resulted in the following error message:

```
Not enough free disk space
The upgrade needs a total of 312 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 312 M of disk space on '/boot'. You can remove old kernels using 'sudo apt autoremove', and you could also set COMPRESS=xz in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf to reduce the size of your initramfs.
```

Trying "sudo apt-get autoremove" resulted in:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’
to correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies. 
linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic : Depends:
linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic but it is not installed 
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic : Depends:
linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic but it is not installed 
linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic
but it is not installed  linux-signed-image-4.13.0-32-generic :
Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic (= 4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1) but it
is not installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Then trying "sudo apt-get -f install" seems to work:

```
sudo apt-get -f install Reading package lists... Done Building
dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Correcting
dependencies... Done The following additional packages will be
installed:   linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic Suggested packages:   fdutils
linux-tools linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 The following NEW
packages will be installed   linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic 0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 0 to
remove and 520 not to upgrade. 26 not fully installed or removed. Need
to get 0 B/78,7 MB of archives. After this operation, 139 MB of
additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

but require additional space within boot, which I don't have...

```
(Reading database ... 547814 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic_4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic (4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic_4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/config-4.13.0-32-generic' to '/boot/config-4.13.0-32-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error


    dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic_4.4.0-104.127_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic (4.4.0-104.127) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic_4.4.0-104.127_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-4.4.0-104-generic' to '/boot/System.map-4.4.0-104-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-104-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-104-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-104-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-104-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic_4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic_4.4.0-104.127_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I then tried purging old kernels using this [Guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space-when-upgrading) and other ones, which, again, won't work, because of unmet dependencies.

So... I feel kinda stuck in a loop here...

Thanks in advance for any answers :).

Same result for all versions:

`sudo dpkg --remove linux-image-extra-4.10.0-38-generic
(Reading database ... 543098 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.10.0-38-generic (4.10.0-38.42~16.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.0-38-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.10.0-38-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-38-generic
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-38-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.10.0-38-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.10.0-38-generic
anthony@entdroid:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic but it is not installed
 linux-signed-image-4.13.0-32-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic (= 4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
anthony@entdroid:~$ sudo apt install --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic but it is not installed
 linux-signed-image-4.13.0-32-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic (= 4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.`

Other things:

`uname -a: 
Linux username 4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 15:57:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ls -alh /boot: 
total 450M
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4,0K Feb 23 20:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4,0K Feb 23 19:14 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,4M Jul 20  2017 abi-4.10.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,4M Okt 10  2017 abi-4.10.0-38-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,4M Nov  9  2017 abi-4.10.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,4M Dez  4  2017 abi-4.10.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,5M Jan 19  2018 abi-4.13.0-31-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Nov 10  2017 abi-4.4.0-101-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Dez  4  2017 abi-4.4.0-103-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Jan 19  2018 abi-4.4.0-112-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Okt 10  2017 abi-4.4.0-98-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 201K Jul 20  2017 config-4.10.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 201K Okt 10  2017 config-4.10.0-38-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 201K Nov  9  2017 config-4.10.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 201K Dez  4  2017 config-4.10.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 209K Jan 19  2018 config-4.13.0-31-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 212K Jan 29 20:28 config-4.15.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 187K Nov 10  2017 config-4.4.0-101-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 187K Dez  4  2017 config-4.4.0-103-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 187K Jan 19  2018 config-4.4.0-112-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 187K Okt 10  2017 config-4.4.0-98-generic
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4,0K Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 1,0K Feb 23 19:14 grub
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 1,0K Nov 19  2017 grub.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  43M Dez 11  2017 initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  43M Dez 11  2017 initrd.img-4.10.0-38-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  43M Dez 11  2017 initrd.img-4.10.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  43M Dez 11  2017 initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Dez 11  2017 initrd.img-4.4.0-101-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Dez 11  2017 initrd.img-4.4.0-103-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Dez 11  2017 initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
drwx------  2 root root  12K Nov 19  2017 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 179K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root 3,6M Jul 20  2017 System.map-4.10.0-28-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,6M Okt 10  2017 System.map-4.10.0-38-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,6M Nov  9  2017 System.map-4.10.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,6M Dez  4  2017 System.map-4.10.0-42-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,7M Jan 19  2018 System.map-4.13.0-31-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,9M Jan 29 20:28 System.map-4.15.0-45-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8M Nov 10  2017 System.map-4.4.0-101-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8M Dez  4  2017 System.map-4.4.0-103-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8M Jan 19  2018 System.map-4.4.0-112-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8M Okt 10  2017 System.map-4.4.0-98-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 7,1M Nov 19  2017 vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 7,1M Okt 10  2017 vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 7,1M Nov 19  2017 vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic.efi.signed
-rw-------  1 root root 7,1M Nov  9  2017 vmlinuz-4.10.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 7,1M Nov 22  2017 vmlinuz-4.10.0-40-generic.efi.signed
-rw-------  1 root root 7,1M Dez  4  2017 vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 7,1M Dez 11  2017 vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic.efi.signed
-rw-------  1 root root 7,4M Jan 19  2018 vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 7,8M Jan 30 11:08 vmlinuz-4.15.0-45-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Nov 10  2017 vmlinuz-4.4.0-101-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Nov 22  2017 vmlinuz-4.4.0-101-generic.efi.signed
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Dez  4  2017 vmlinuz-4.4.0-103-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Dez 11  2017 vmlinuz-4.4.0-103-generic.efi.signed
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Jan 19  2018 vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Okt 10  2017 vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Nov 19  2017 vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic.efi.signed`

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the images manually no other choice, first type `uname -a` to see what kernel version you are using and delete all other versions.

Paste the uname -a and ls -alh /boot output and I will give you the command to delete.

```
rm -rf /boot/abi-4.13.*;rm -rf /boot/abi-4.4.*;rm -rf /boot/initrd.img-4.13.*;rm -rf /boot/initrd.img-4.4.*; rm -rf /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-38-generic; rm -rf /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-40-generic  /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.* /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.*
```

then you can retry and it must work

Comment: Seems like a partial answer - the system and apt will have different ideas of the system's current state. How should the OP fix apt afterward?

Comment: The apt issue was trigger due full /boot partition, please do an apt-get -f install and you will see

Comment: Says permission denied for any and all removals.

Comment: use sudo  `sudo rm -rf /boot/abi-4.13.* /boot/abi-4.4.* /boot/initrd.img-4.13.* /boot/initrd.img-4.4.* /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-38-generic /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-40-generic  /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.* /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.*

Comment: do a reboot please after deleting the files

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: List all the old kernels that you need to remove. That's easy - you already printed the list above. Simply write down or print it out the kernel version numbers. Do not include the currently running kernel on the list.

Step 2: Use dpkg to remove one old kernel. Example: `sudo dpkg --remove linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic`

Step 3: Try `sudo apt autoremove` and `sudo apt install --fix-missing` again.

If you get the same out-of-space error, then repeat Step 2 with another old kernel.

As you free up space by removing each old kernel, eventually you will have enough space for --fix missing to work. Then autoremove will, in turn, work.

You also seem to to have over 500 packages awaiting upgrade. Once you have apt working properly again, upgrade them.

Quarterly or so, run autoremove to properly clean out /boot and keep your out-of-space problem from returning.